# Interesting map and flatMap observations - Future, Scala

Tags: scala

I noticed few interesting behaviour about map, flatMap and Future but I am not able to understand what is causing this behaviour

```
//I have 3 Future objects. 

object ConcurrencyExample extends App {

  val time = System.currentTimeMillis()


 val future1 = Future{println("future1");1}
  val future2 = Future{println("future2");2}
  val future3 = Future{println("future3");3}

//I want to add 1,2 and 3. I can do it using flatMap

val result = future1 flatMap (f1=> future2.flatMap(f2 => future3.map(f3=> f3+f2+f1) ) )

result onComplete{
    case Success(v)=>println("result is "+v)
    case Failure(e) =>println("failed result:"+e)
  }


  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

result

```
future2
future1
future3
result is 6
```

If I change the code above to map, I get an empty List(). I am unable to track where this empty List came from?

```
val result = future1 map (f1=> future2.map(f2 => future3.map(f3=> f3+f2+f1) ) )
```

result

```
future3
future2
future1
result is List()
```

If I use only two Future objects and map, I get Success(3) and not an empty List()

```
val result = future1 map (f1=> future2.map(f2 => f2+f1) )
```

result

```
future3
future2
future1
result is Success(3)
```

Comment: If you upgrade to the latest version of Scala 2.11 or directly to Scala 2.12.x then you'll see a much niced string representation than "List()"

Comment: Details on what Viktor is saying are at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9488. Note that Scala 2.11.9 hasn't been released yet, so there isn't an official 2.11 release with the fix yet (the 2.11 nightlies have it).

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the result return type is `Future[Int]`, In the second case the result return type is `Future[Future[...]]` (some nested Future)

In the first case when you do the onComplete that is

```
val result: Future[Int] = ???

result onComplete { println }
```

The above code will return `Success(1)`

In the second case

```
val result: Future[Future[..]] = ???

result onComplete { println }
```

This may result unevaluated Future that is why you see `List()`. See the Scala repl output below. Look at the result type of `Future { Thread.sleep(1000); 1 }`

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val f = Future { Thread.sleep(1000); 1 }
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = List()

scala> f onComplete { println }
Success(1)
```

**Suggestion**

Know the difference between flatMap and map and know when to use flatMap and map.